# Convert dictionary to an array in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

How can I convert this array or dictionary on Swift  {f = 12 ; z = 9 ; k = 65 }

on this style {f = 12 , z = 9 , k = 65 }, because my console in Swift shows me the first list

thank you

Comment: And how would you see this as an array? What would be the type of its elements?

Comment: On my console, this question is related to that question [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601486/insert-an-nsdictionary-in-a-tableview-from-parse-cloud), if you can help me I will be happy

Comment: @vrwim  some thoughts ?

Comment: {f = 12 ; z = 9 ; k = 65 } is this a string or response from WebService

Comment: @Shardul from my console in Xcode when I run a function from parse cloud  code, when I print the result of that function

Comment: did you print dictionary object

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601486/insert-an-nsdictionary-in-a-tableview-from-parse-cloud) it's related to this question

Comment: In Parse you get an array [AnyObjects] so you need to cast that to [PFObject] first.  When you get a PFObjet you can access all its structure (pointers and arrays of pointers) using the dot notation directly on the PFObject and all the nice properties of an NSObject.  I am therefore not sure why you would want to convert that into a dictionary: it does not sound like an approach that fits the result format of your query.

Answer (score 0):

This `{f = 12 ; z = 9 ; k = 65 }` format is just what you see, it's a printed format of an NSDictionary: it's not the actual syntax of the data structure, it's a representation.

For example:

```
let dict = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["f":12, "z":9, "k":65])
```

If I print it:

```
print(dict)
```

I get this in the console:

> {
>       f = 12;
>       k = 65;
>       z = 9;
>   }

But the content is still this:

> ["z": 9, "k": 65, "f": 12]

And is usable as usual:

```
if let ef = dict["f"] as? Int {
    print("'f' is an Int: \(ef)")
}
```

Result:

> 'f' is an Int: 12